# JavaScript: What means "relative to the viewport"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

From MDN Element.getBoundingClientRect-article: [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

"*The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.*"

**What is "relative to the viewport"?**

Does someone know a page where this is shown with some graphic. 
The MDN-page misses that sadly ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The viewport is the area where your browser shows you (a section) of a website.

```
>> var header = document.getElementById('question-header')
<div id="question-header">

>> header.getBoundingClientRect()
DOMRect { x: 183.61666870117188, y: 84, width: 1060, height: 54.149993896484375, top: 84, right: 1243.6166687011719, bottom: 138.14999389648438, left: 183.61666870117188 }
```

[image: getBoundingClientRect()]

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43829528/1307866))

Comment: are you sure you've drawn "right" value correctly on this picture? According to MDN `right` is `left+width`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRect

Answer (score 2):

The **Viewport** is nothing but the device screen on which your application is running.

From Google:

> The viewport is the user's visible area of a web page. The viewport varies with the device, and will be smaller on a mobile phone than on a computer screen.

Here are some graphical views. For desktop view, here is the viewport

[image]

For Mobile / Tablets, here how it looks like

[image]

**Note: The images are taken from the google just to demonstrate you**

Now **Relative to the viewport** for `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` means get the position relative to the **viewport**, that is from the corners in which your web page is rendered.

I hope that makes sense to you. Feel free to ask any questions :)